# How to load picture images via click on a picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment i load default images for every picture in my app. I want to load the real picture of all images in div 5 if i click on any picture of div 5. At the moment i use the onclick event of the img tag with:

```
switchImg(this, "LINK_FOR_PICTURE")
```

my js snippet:

```
function switchImg(img, url){
  $(img).attr("src", url);
}
```

At the moment it only loads the picture that i clicked on.

here the HTML snippet:

```
<div id="1">
</div>

<div id="2">
</div>

..

<div id="5">

<img src="DEFAULT_IMG" onclick="switchImg(this, "LINK_FOR_PICTURE_1")" alt="No_picture">
</div>
<img src="DEFAULT_IMG" onclick="switchImg(this, "LINK_FOR_PICTURE_2")" alt="No_picture">
</div>
<img src="DEFAULT_IMG" onclick="switchImg(this, "LINK_FOR_PICTURE_3")" alt="No_picture">
</div>
.....

</div>
```

How do i need to change my code that following condition is true:

- i click on any picture in div id=5 and all this pictures gets the correct picture link (LINK_FOR_PICTURE_1, LINK_FOR_PICTURE_2, etc) as src. The other pictures in the other divs don`t change and still display the default img. (Div id 5 is an example the same procedure should be possible for other divs with pictures).

Please keep in mind that the img link changes for every picture.

Comment: Can you make your question little more clear?

Comment: you should explain what should be clicked and what should be loaded and where...

Comment: I tryed to make it more clear. //edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. using only numbers for id is bad practice
2. your div id="5" is closed right after first image
3. you are using double quotes in double quotes in your example - bad idea
4. by calling switchImg(this, "LINK_FOR_PICTURE_3") using this, "this"
   represents only clicked image. You would need something like

   ```
   function switchImg(img){

       $(img).closest('div').find('img').each(function(){

           $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('imglink'));

       });

   }
   ```

using html

```
<img src="DEFAULT_IMG" onclick="switchImg(this);" imglink="LINK_FOR_PICTURE_3" alt="No_picture">
```

Comment: so you're recommending inline JS and invalid HTML?

Comment: ok, attribute name should be data-imglink to be completely valid.
and inline javascript is perfectly fine if used in a good browser (sandboxed tabs)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

HTML

```
<div id="5">
    <img src="DEFAULT_IMG" data-fullImg="link_for_picture1" alt="No_picture">
    <img src="DEFAULT_IMG" data-fullImg="link_for_picture1" alt="No_picture">
    <img src="DEFAULT_IMG" data-fullImg="link_for_picture1" alt="No_picture">
</div>
```

JS
    function switchImg(img){
        img.attr("src", img.data('fullImg'));
    }

```
$(function(){    
    var allImages = $('#5 img');

    allImages.click(function(){
        allImages.each(function(){
            switchImg($(this));
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML changes**

- I assume you want all the `img` tags wrapped in `#5`, no? Because your current HTML markup is invalid.
- Additionally, ids can't technically start with a number. It probably won't cause a problem in most browsers, but it is invalid.
- I'm using an HTML5 data-attribute to store the link for the picture. This will work even in non-HTML5 browsers. I'll get to this in a moment.
- Finally, inline-JS is generally a bad idea because it is difficult to maintain. Using jQuery, it's very easy to bind code to the onclick event.

**JS Changes**

- `allImages.click()` binds the code inside to the click event on any of the images.
- The `.each()` function then loops over all those images, passing itself as a jquery object to the switchImg function.
- My modified version of the switchImg function doesn't need a second parameter, because it can simply use the jQuery object to access the `data-fullImg` attribute. If using a version of jQuery prior to 1.6 (or something like that), using the `.data()` method in the way I did won't work. You'd instead need to use `.attr('data-fullImg')`.

**EDIT**

In response to the OP's comment on this post:

```
$(function(){
    $('img.showOriginal').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children().each(function(){
            switchImg($(this));
        });
    });
});
```

This code assumes that you put the class"showOriginal" on every `img` tag, since I doubt that you truly want to apply this functionality to every single `img` tag on the page. Beyond that, we have this part: `$(this).parent().children()`. That simply traverses the DOM up to the parent element (#5, #2, whatever), and then back down to all the children (the images you want to change).

Comment: Okay this look very good, thanks for that. My question was not that good, problem is now: Div id 5 was an exampl,e the same procedure should be possible for other divs with pictures

Comment: Why would you observe the images only to traverse back up the dom to then collect it's children, if you really wanted to do this correctly you would observe the click only on the DIV and then collect it's children.

Comment: That's true, but I don't know if the OP is putting anything else in that div.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of jQuery and event delegation and observe when the div is clicked to then find all the images within that div and trigger the src change. To explain this better i've quickly  thrown together an example on JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Phunky/EnhUE/

In my example you can either click images individually or the div for them all.

Comment: -1. This is an extremely inefficient approach, and doesn't achieve what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Really? Do explain why this is inefficient.

Comment: +1 I stand corrected. I always thought both `.live()` and `.delegate()` were less efficient than `.bind()`, but it appears that `.delegate()` is actually MORE efficient in many cases. And this would be one of those cases. *Edit* - I tried to change my vote on this, but it's not letting me unless your response gets edited.

Comment: Well if you looked at the example before commenting you would notice that I used on() due to using the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Jeez, calm down. I did look at it. And since `on()` is somewhat of a combination between `.delegate()` and `.live()`, AND I was wrong about the efficiency of `delegate()`, I made my comment.